# How to Remove Consecutive Word/Sentence in Hive Using Regular Expression

Tags: regex, hive

I have a string column that takes sequence of pages a customer visits during his/her visits. When the page is refreshed the same page name repeats consecutively. I want to use regexp_replace function to identify and remove the duplicate page.

**Example**:
Home Page, Product list page, Product list page, Product details page, Review Page, Review Page, Product list page, Product details page

**Expected Output**:
Home Page, Product list page, Product details page, Review Page, Product list page, Product details page

I built the following regular expression to identify individual page names 
`(\b([a-zA-Z]+)\b\s?)+` but not sure how to look for the repeated page with in the string and remove them.

Appreciate any help !

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - my bad, missed the "consecutively"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to remove only *consecutive* identical items separated with a comma.

You may use a regex based on a positive lookahead, [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html).

```
select  regexp_replace
        (
            column_name
           ,'([^,]+),\\s*(?=\\1(?:,|$))'
           ,''
        )

from    mytable
;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mjTvhs/1).

**Pattern details**:

- `([^,]+)` - Group 1 capturing 1+ chars other than `,`
- `,` - a comma
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?=\\1(?:,|$))` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there is the same text as in Group 1 right after the 0+ whitespaces and there is a `,` or end of string after that text, else, it fails the match.

Here, `\1` is the backreference to the text captured in Group 1.